# Installing package `ade4` in R

Tags: r, r-package

I am trying to install some R packages, using Packrat (no root on this machine) on a linux machine. One of the packages failed to install, due to a dependency on 'ade4'. When trying to install 'ade4', I got the following:

```
* installing *source* package ‘ade4’ ...
** package ‘ade4’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c adesub.c -o adesub.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c divsub.c -o divsub.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c fourthcorner.c -o fourthcorner.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c phylog.c -o phylog.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c testamova.c -o testamova.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c testdim.c -o testdim.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c testrlq.c -o testrlq.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c tests.c -o tests.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o ade4.so adesub.o divsub.o fourthcorner.o init.o phylog.o testamova.o testdim.o testrlq.o tests.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'ade4.so' failed
make: *** [ade4.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ade4’
* removing ‘/users/studs/bsc/2013/barashe/paprbag/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.4.3/ade4’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpnD67Gk/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("ade4") :
  installation of package ‘ade4’ had non-zero exit status
> /usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'ade4.so' failed
```

Tried searching for solutions, but could not find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three libraries are missing on your computer. liblapack liblas and libgfortran. You must install them first to compile this package

```
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev libgfortran-8-dev
```

But if your are not an administrator I don't know how to solve this issue.

Comment: I can contact my administrator and try this. Thanks!